# Somehow I built SWI-Prolog without unbounded integer support. I need to use a predicate that requires this support

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I reinstalled my OS and thus re-installed SWI-Prolog.

Here are the exact commands I ran for the installation.

```
git clone https://github.com/SWI-Prolog/swipl-devel.git
cd swipl-devel
git submodule update --init

cd swipl-devel
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local/logic -G Ninja ..
ninja
ctest -j 4
ninja install
```

I run into problems when trying to use the non-ninja method of installation (but that's a whole other post).

When I start swipl I get this revealing message

```
(ins)nick@nickSUSE:~/prolog/scheduler> swipl base.pl
Warning: /home/nick/prolog/scheduler/base.pl:1:
Warning:    Using CLP(FD) with bounded arithmetic may yield wrong results.

blah blah blah
```

The only reason I figured out that this happened is because the most fundamental predicates in my entire project are based off of [divmod/4](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=divmod/4)! The documentation clearly states that this predicate can only be used if swipl was installed with unbound integer support.

I re-installed SWI-Prolog and got the same problem. What can I do to be able to use divmod/4?

Comment: Did you install packages `gmp` and `gmp-devel` before running `cmake`? The command to install it is probably [`zypper`](https://en.opensuse.org/SDB:Zypper_manual_%28plain%29) `install gmp gmp-devel`.  Then remove everything in `build` and redo everything starting from the `cmake` command.

Comment: Why are you building SWI-Prolog? There are completed builds available for [download](https://www.swi-prolog.org/download/stable). I just checked my Windows and Linux PPA installs using `current_prolog_flag(bounded,Value).` and both versions have  unbounded integers.

Comment: After installing gmp and gmp-devel I rebuilt it and now have access to divmod/4. Thank you.

Comment: @NicholasHubbard Let's formalize this. I will move the comment to an answer, then you can accept it so that this question is done.

Comment: @GuyCoder On Linux, the manual itself says "build it": "The official packages are often out of date. PPAs and snaps are created automatically for every release ... Installing from source is often the best option for installing on Linux and *BSD based systems. Building is not complex." (https://eu.swi-prolog.org/build/unix.html)

Comment: @DavidTonhofer `the manual itself says "build it"` Then submit a change. Even Anne thought it was always suppose to be built but Jan W. clarified that. ([ref](https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/t/wiki-discussion-swi-prolog-connecting-to-postgresql-via-odbc/2405/16?u=ericgt))

Comment: @GuyCoder But why? I _do_ think Linux people _should_ build it. You don't think so?

Comment: @DavidTonhofer `The official packages are often out of date.` I know the DockerHub  image is out of date, but please show where the others are out of date. I know that if a patch is added you can pick it up in a Windows build the next day with the [daily builds](https://www.swi-prolog.org/download/daily/bin/). I can't remember where to pick up the Unix daily builds.

Comment: @GuyCoder I don't know. Just citing the manual here,

Comment: @DavidTonhofer `You don't think so?` No, use `apt-get` or what ever is specific to that Linux distro.

Comment: @DavidTonhofer `Building is not complex` Doesn't this question by the OP say otherwise?

Comment: @GuyCoder Datapoint: On my Fedora 31/30 systems, that would leave me with SWI-Prolog 8.0.3 (currently 8.3.9)

Comment: @DavidTonhofer `You don't think so?` No, get the PPA if one exist  or what ever is specific to that Linux distro.

Comment: @GuyCoder "not complex" ... As I said, just citing the manual. Don't be mad at me. The build procedure DOES have its warts.

Comment: @DavidTonhofer `that would leave me with SWI-Prolog 8.0.3 (currently 8.3.9)` Do you use anything in the gap? Most of the stuff Jan puts in the newer releases is so new, patches or a beta that unless you need it you don't. Most of the time I only upgrade to verify a possible bug if an OP is using a version newer than what I have, or need something new like when I wanted concurrent_forall/3.

Comment: @DavidTonhofer Where are referencing that SWI-Prolog for Fedora is available at version 8.0.3? I only see that on the Fedora page it says you need to [build it](https://www.swi-prolog.org/build/Redhat.html). I am asking because I should add a [WIki](https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/c/wiki/12) about this as I never really paid attention to the releases except for Windows, Ubuntu and Mac and I don't own a Mac so can test or write about them.

Comment: @DavidTonhofer I don't know if you have been following my posts at the SWI-Prolog forum, but I am looking into using [Developing inside a Container](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers) which, if it works and I don't know why it wont, will significantly change my standard development environment. This means I will rely on the [swipl](https://hub.docker.com/_/swipl) Docker container at DockerHub going forward, or be building my own until someone takes over ownership of updating the container.

Comment: @GuyCoder _"Where are referencing that SWI-Prolog for Fedora is available at version 8.0.3"_. Right on the system: `dnf info pl` --> `Version: 8.0.3, Release: 1.fc30, Summary: SWI-Prolog - Edinburgh compatible Prolog compiler`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you install packages `gmp` and `gmp-devel` before running cmake?

The command to install it is probably (using [`zypper`](https://en.opensuse.org/SDB:Zypper_manual_%28plain%29)):

```
zypper install libgmp10 gmp-devel
```

Then remove everything in directory `build` and restart from the `cmake` command.